# address of a reference of packed member is not equal to address of packed member?

Tags: c++

I compiled this program by g++.  And it printed "unequal".
And it prints "equal" if I don't use "packed" attribute.
I don't know how "packed" attribute cause the differnece.

By the way,
executable built by clang++ prints "equal".

```
#include <iostream>

struct __attribute__ ((packed)) Packed {
  char a;
  int b;
  int c;
  char d;
};

void test(const int &i, int *ptr) {
  std::cout << ((&i == ptr) ? "equal" : "unequal") << std::endl;
}

int main () {
  Packed p;
  p.c = 1;
  test(p.c, &p.c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: __attribute__((packed)) variable attribute
It specifies that a member field has the smallest possible alignment. That is, one byte for a variable field, and one bit for a bitfield, unless you specify a larger value with the aligned attribute.

Answer (score 10):

When compiling with GCC or CLANG, there is a warning saying that `taking address of packed member of 'Packed' may result in an unaligned pointer value` which means that behavior of your code is unspecified. That's why you have different outputs when compiling with GCC and CLANG.

**What does the `__attribute__ ((packed))` mean?**

The packed variable attribute specifies that a structure field has the smallest possible alignment. That is, one byte for a variable field, and one bit for a bitfield, unless you specify a larger value with the aligned attribute.

**Why not to take the address of a packed member?**

Taking the address of a packed member is dangerous since the reduced
alignment of the pointee is lost. This can lead to memory alignment
faults in some architectures if the pointer value is dereferenced.

**References:**

- [Warn when taking address of packed member](https://reviews.llvm.org/D20561)
- [__attribute__((packed)) variable attribute](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124982232.htm)

Comment: Regarding your quote: _"Taking the address of a packed member is dangerous since the reduced alignment of the pointee is lost. This can lead to memory alignment faults in some architectures if the pointer value is dereferenced."_ In what architectures can this be dangerous? How about on x86-64?